# JavaScript: Event Listeners with Callbacks and Parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback, event-listener

I have an event handler which (a) requires parameters, and (b) calls a callback function via `window.setTimeout`. I use `bind` to attach the event handler.

The called function is called with additional parameters. I have tried both `callback(parameters)` and `callback.call(*this*,parameters).

Below is a code sample:

```
var element=document.querySelector('h1');
element.onclick=function(e) {
    delay(test.bind(element,'from original','also from original',e));
}
function test(a,b,c,d,e) {
    alert(this);    //  element
    alert(a);       //  from original
    alert(b);       //  also from original
    alert(c);       //  event
    alert(d);       //  from delayed
    alert(e);       //  also from delayed
}
function delay(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(delayed,100);
    function delayed() {
        //  callback.call(this,'from delayed','also from delayed');
        callback('from delayed','also from delayed');
    }
}
```

I my testing, I find that callback gets the parameters in the following order:

1. Parameters from the original function
2. The event itself
3. Parameters from the function calling the callback

Further, I find that the callback function has `this` set to the original element, even if I call it using `.call` with the `this` argument set to anything (even `null`).

I can handle this certainty, but I am confused as to how this is formally handled. I can’t find anything in the documentation which discusses an event listener with a callback.

The question is:

1. Where is the ordering of the parameters documented?
2. Where does `this` come from, and why does it seem to ignore any attempts to change ie?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the `bind()` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So this line: `test.bind(element,'from original','also from original',e)`

will return a function that when called will use those provided arguments first, and any subsequent arguments after those. So when calling your function, it will result in the order you list above.

---

As for `this`, the problem is that you are using `setTimeout()` after the bind, which is why you might not be getting what you are expecting. You can read more about `setTimeout()` and `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem).